# dynamically setAttribute Style FILL using data variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of arrays to set the start position, weidth and name of some chart elements in a SVG. What I haven't been able to achieve is setting the colour of each of those elements using HEX values from an array called chart_color.

Currently you'll see I've set the value of fill to green. What I tried and failed with is fill: chart_color[num].

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<svg id="mysvg" width="1000" height="800"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<text x="50" y="60" fill="black" 
     font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
     font-size="28">Revenue and Expenses</text>
<line x1="150" y1="80" x2="150" y2="320" 
   style="stroke:rgb(155, 144, 144);stroke-width:5" />
<script type="application/ecmascript"> <![CDATA[
   var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
   var chart_start = [152, 84, 152]
   var chart_width = [100,64,36]
   var chart_names = ["Revenue", "Expenses","Profit"]
   var chart_color = ["#28CE6D","#DF3456","#4DC7EC"]
   var num = 3;

   while (num-- > 0)
   {
     var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
         rect.setAttribute("x", chart_start[num]);
         rect.setAttribute("y", [num] * 70 + 100);
         rect.setAttribute("width", chart_width[num]);
         rect.setAttribute("height", "50");
         rect.setAttribute("style", "fill:green;stroke:black;stroke-width:0;opacity:1");
         mysvg.appendChild(rect);
   }  
     ]]></script>
   </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the index (num) of the chart_color array and apply that as a variable within in your style declaration (breaking out of the string).

Note that you are also setting the border to stroke: black - but hte stroke width to 0 - So it can be seen I have amended that to stroke-width: 1 so that the border on each shows up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<svg id="mysvg" width="1000" height="800"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<text x="50" y="60" fill="black" 
     font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
     font-size="28">Revenue and Expenses</text>
<line x1="150" y1="80" x2="150" y2="320" 
   style="stroke:rgb(155, 144, 144);stroke-width:5" />
<script type="application/ecmascript"> <![CDATA[
   var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
   var chart_start = [152, 84, 152]
   var chart_width = [100,64,36]
   var chart_names = ["Revenue", "Expenses","Profit"]
   var chart_color = ["#28CE6D","#DF3456","#4DC7EC"]
   var num = 3;

   while (num-- > 0)
   {
     var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
         rect.setAttribute("x", chart_start[num]);
         rect.setAttribute("y", [num] * 70 + 100);
         rect.setAttribute("width", chart_width[num]);
         rect.setAttribute("height", "50");
         rect.setAttribute("style", "fill:" + chart_color[num] + ";stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1");
         mysvg.appendChild(rect);
   }  
     ]]></script>
   </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are welcome - happy to help. Have fun with your coding.

Answer (score 3):

With style attributes you can actually assign them a value without using the setAttribute function:

```
rect.style.fill = chart_color[num]
```

But use this method consistently so that you don't override the style attribute, like setting color to "red" then setting style to "width:100px".

Comment: As a note - if you are using a two word style name (such as "stroke-width") then you will need to camelCase it if you are applying it in the js - eg: rect.style.strokeWidth = 0;

Comment: thanks for this, I went with the one below for consistency but like this also, kind regards, Matt